# How can I reset the laptop battery BMS?

Tags: batteries, laptop

My laptop is an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-51.

The laptop won't turn on - it only turns on when the power adapter is attached.  I checked the BMS output voltage with my multimeter and it was 0 V, but each cell voltage is fine.

I thought the battery BMS is shorted or broken.

I found [a video about resetting the laptop BMS](https://youtu.be/W4qo4OheFZI) by shorting some points, but in my laptop battery BMS, I cannot figure out where to short.

Can someone help me to reset the battery?

[image: battery picture 1]

[image: battery picture 2]

[image: battery picture 3]

Comment: Most of them will permanently lock out with pretty much no way for anyone outside of the factory to reset it. If you have the experience, knowledge about the dangers and the equipment, you can try to recharge it directly but chances are high that the BMS won’t budge.

Comment: Once a Li-ion battery goes to 0 volts, it's permanently damaged and cannot be recharged. If that reading is due only to the controller, you might be able to salvage an individual cell or more, bur, as @winny states, with risk of fire or worse.

Comment: @DrMoishe Your categoric statement 0 V = bad cell is not true. I’ve recharged plenty of cells from 0 V and they turn out to be fine, mainly Panasonic cells. Most cells are ruined though.

Comment: Oh i missed one thing. The cell voltage is fine. Just bms output voltage is 0v. It should be 15v but probably something was shorted in bms circuit so i want to reset the bms

Comment: I had a somewhat similar problem with a pack that refused to be charged. But I measured that a power cycle provoked a short try by the BMS. So I did multiple power cycles, actually about 30 or so, and finally the BMS started charging. Perhaps this is an experiment you could do, too.

Comment: What's the code/number on the two chips?

Comment: The big one is BQ40 Z555 T1 751 CO97. The small one is Q5A G4 195

Comment: @busybee interesting! When you say `I did multiple power cycles, actually about 30 or so` . At what frequency? (Like 10 seconds for each power cycle, 5 seconds in between?). Did you try it on other battery packs? Did you find other technics to revive other PC batteries?